# Error report - SQL Error: ORA-31061: XDB error: XML event error ORA-19202: Error occurred

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g

I have the below error message when I run the query to inject an XML file into a table on Oracle.

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-31061: XDB error: XML event error
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
In line 124110683 of orastream:
LPX-00225: end-element tag "title" does not match start-element tag "sue"
```

The query is

```
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE2 (xml_file) 
(SELECT XMLTYPE(bfilename('EXPORT_DUMPS','WR_2007_20150123103151_DSSHPSH_0002.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')) from dual );
```

The XML content looks correct. Here the lines 124110601-150, but I don't see anything special at line 83, which should correspond to line 124110683 mentioned in the error message.

```
<citedWork>PHYSICAL REVIEW B</citedWork>
<doi>10.1103/PhysRevB.68.020403</doi>
</reference>
<reference>
<uid>WOS:000236477800002</uid>
<citedAuthor>Erdinc, A</citedAuthor>
<year>2006</year>
<page>6</page>
<volume>301</volume>
<citedTitle>Multicritical behavior of the antiferromagnetic Blume-Emery-Griffiths model with the repulsive biquadratic coupling in an external magnetic field</citedTitle>
<citedWork>JOURNAL OF MAGNETISM AND MAGNETIC MATERIALS</citedWork>
<doi>10.1016/j.jmmm.2005.06.002</doi>
</reference>
<reference>
<uid>WOS:000236631400004</uid>
<citedAuthor>Keskin, M</citedAuthor>
<year>2006</year>
<page>116</page>
<volume>353</volume>
<citedTitle>Multicritical phase diagrams of the antiferromagnetic spin-3/2 Blume-Capel model</citedTitle>
<citedWork>PHYSICS LETTERS A</citedWork>
<doi>10.1016/j.physleta.2005.12.079</doi>
</reference>
<reference>
<uid>WOS:000237000300021</uid>
<citedAuthor>Keskin, M</citedAuthor>
<year>2006</year>
<page>263</page>
<volume>364</volume>
<citedTitle>Multicritical behavior of the antiferromagnetic spin-3/2 Blume-Emery-Griffiths model</citedTitle>
<citedWork>PHYSICA A-STATISTICAL MECHANICS AND ITS APPLICATIONS</citedWork>
<doi>10.1016/j.physa.2005.08.077</doi>
</reference>
<reference>
<uid>WOS:000255098600003.7</uid>
<citedAuthor>BACKHICH A</citedAuthor>
<year>2001</year>
<page>249</page>
<volume>13</volume>
<citedWork>J PHYS CONDENS MATT</citedWork>
</reference>
<reference>
<uid>WOS:000246760500003.15</uid>
<citedAuthor>KIKUCHI R</citedAuthor>
<year>1979</year>
<citedWork>UNPUB CRYSTALS STAT</citedWork>
</reference>
</references>
<addresses count="2">
<address_name>
<address_spec addr_no="1">
<full_address>Erciyes Univ, Inst Sci, TR-38039 Kayseri, Turkey</full_address>
<organizations count="1">
<organization>Erciyes Univ</organization>
</organizations>
<suborganizations count="1">
<suborganization>Inst Sci</suborganization>
</suborganizations>
<city>Kayseri</city>
<country>Turkey</country>
<zip location="BC">TR-38039</zip>
</address_spec>
</address_name>
<address_name>
<address_spec addr_no="2">
<full_address>Erciyes Univ, Dept Phys, TR-38039 Kayseri, Turkey</full_address>
<organizations count="1">
<organization>Erciyes Univ</organization>
</organizations>
<suborganizations count="1">
<suborganization>Dept Phys</suborganization>
</suborganizations>
<city>Kayseri</city>
<country>Turkey</country>
<zip location="BC">TR-38039</zip>
</address_spec>
</address_name>
</addresses>
<category_info>
<headings count="1">
<heading>Science &amp; Technology</heading>
</headings>
<subheadings count="1">
<subheading>Physical Sciences</subheading>
</subheadings>
<subjects count="4">
<subject ascatype="traditional">Chemistry, Physical</subject>
<subject ascatype="traditional">Physics, Multidisciplinary</subject>
<subject ascatype="extended">Chemistry</subject>
<subject ascatype="extended">Physics</subject>
</subjects>
</category_info>
<keywords count="4">
<keyword>spin-3/2 Blume-Emery-Griffiths model</keyword>
<keyword>cluster variation method</keyword>
<keyword>thermal variations of order parameters</keyword>
<keyword>phase diagrams</keyword>
</keywords>
<abstracts count="1">
<abstract>
<abstract_text count="1">
<p>The critical behaviour of the ferromagnetic spin-3/2 Blume-Emery-Griffiths model with repulsive biquadratic coupling in the absence and presence of an external magnetic field is studied by using the lowest approximation of the cluster variation method, which is identical with the mean-field approximation. Thermal variations of the order parameters are investigated for different values of the interaction parameters and the external magnetic field. The complete phase diagrams of the system are calculated in the (kT /J, K / J), (kT /J, D / J) and (kT /J, H / J) planes. Five new phase diagram topologies are obtained, which are either absent from previous approaches or have gone unnoticed. A detailed discussion and comparison of the phase diagrams is made.</p>
</abstract_text>
</abstract>
</abstracts>
</fullrecord_metadata>
<item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:type="itemType_wos">
<ids avail="Y">171UI</ids>
<bib_id>62 (3-4): 127-139 MAR-APR 2007</bib_id>
<bib_pagecount type="Journal">124</bib_pagecount>
<reprint_contact>
<address_spec addr_no="1">
<full_address>Erciyes Univ, Inst Sci, TR-38039 Kayseri, Turkey</full_address>
<organizations count="1">
<organization>Erciyes Univ</organization>
</organizations>
<suborganizations count="1">
<suborganization>Inst Sci</suborganization>
</suborganizations>
<city>Kayseri</city>
<country>Turkey</country>
<zip location="BC">TR-38039</zip>
</address_spec>
<names count="1">
<name addr_no="1" reprint="Y" role="author" seq_no="1">
<display_name>Ali Pinar, M.</display_name>
<full_name>Ali Pinar, M.</full_name>
<wos_standard>Pinar, MA</wos_standard>
<first_name>M.</first_name>
<last_name>Ali Pinar</last_name>
<email_addr>keskin@erciyes.edu.tr</email_addr>
</name>
</names>
</reprint_contact>
<keywords_plus count="5">
<keyword>MULTICRITICAL PHASE-DIAGRAMS</keyword>
<keyword>RECURSION METHOD</keyword>
<keyword>ISING-MODEL</keyword>
<keyword>LATTICE</keyword>
<keyword>FIELD</keyword>
</keywords_plus>
</item>
</static_data>
<dynamic_data>
<cluster_related>
<identifiers>
<identifier type="accession_no" value="171UI"/>
<identifier type="issn" value="0932-0784"/>
</identifiers>
</cluster_related>
</dynamic_data>
</REC>
```

I have no problems with other lighter XML files. This one is almost of 5 GB.

We are running the: ''Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.4.0 64bit Production''

Does anyone knows where the problem could be?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your xml is corrupt. check it with and xml checker tool

Comment: when I try to open it with XML Spy I get this error: 'An unknown error occurred while accessing an unnamed file'. I can read the XML content with Ultra Edit but I don't know how to check whether it's corrupted or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: That snippet doesn't have title or sue tags, so the line numbers seem to be unhelpful. Can you search for those tags in your editor?

Comment: I am having big problems in opening this file as it is of 5 GB and it seems that my pc cannot allocate enough memory... I'm trying everything but without solution...

Comment: I'll cut it with HJSplit!

Comment: I've no found the tag <sue> but looking for "sue" I've found this as a name in different email addresses that seem to be corrected. The only "strange" row could be the below `<citedTitle>Scientists, activists sue south Africa's AIDS 'denialists'</citedTitle>` as there are '' inside... but I'm not sure...

Comment: this is really strange, as I have cut the file in 23 little files and uploaded into the table without any issue...